# How to write @font-face for Chrome

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

Here is my @font-face in css:

```
@font-face{
    font-family: CamphorW01-Thin;
    src: local(CamphorW01-Thin), 
         url('/usr/share/fonts/opentype/Camphor W01 Thin.otf');
}
```

The fallback is for end-users that don't have the custom font installed.

I have installed the custom fonts on Ubuntu 18.04 server (in the cloud), but when I access the site from my local Chrome browser, the dev console shows:

GET http://(IPAddress)/usr/share/fonts/opentype/Camphor%20W01%20Thin.otf 404 (not found)

The custom fonts are installed in /usr/share/fonts/opentype/ and /usr/share/fonts/truetype/, and the font cache was rebuilt.  When I issue the command fc-list, the fonts appear in the list.  I checked the spelling and path, and it all matches.

Is there something wrong with my @font-face line shown above?  Or is it something else?

Thanks for the help.  I'm very puzzled.

Answer (score 1):

The URL needs to be a URL, not a path. Your users can't access `/usr/share` from their browsers.

Comment: Thanks.  How would I construct the url in my @font-face rule?

Comment: Put the fonts on a publicly accessible URL and use that.

Comment: For example, within my web root I can put a fonts folder and the @font-face rule would read mydomain.com/fonts/(font name)?  But Ubuntu doesn't install them there.  Does that matter?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter. You'd typically use font files specifically optimized for webfont usage, anyways. Run the `.otf` files through something like https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator and use what it spits out.